# Inserting data into DB

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I need to save the information inserted in that form C# : 
[image: Error1]

Into my table in an Access 2003 DB : FattureVoci

The query in my C# is :

```
cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO FattureVoci ([IDVoce],[CodiceArticolo],[Descrizione],[Quantita],[PrezzoUnitario]) VALUES (@Id,@Prod,@Descr,@Qta,@Prezzo)";
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Categ", this.Categoria.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prod", this.Prodotto.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", this.Data.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Iva", Convert.ToInt32(this.PartitaIVA.Text) );
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descr", this.Descrizione.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qta", Convert.ToInt32(this.Qta.Text));
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Intest", this.Intestatario.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(this.id.Text));
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prezzo", Convert.ToInt32(this.Prezzo.Text));
```

And the fields in my DB are : 
[image: Error2]

The error is ( Types of data mismatch in criteria expression ) : 
[image: Erorr3]

Comment: You declared 5 parameter in your sql command but you try to add 9 parameter values? Could you please translate your exception to English? What are the column types exactly?

Comment: uhhmmm can you understand the error?

Comment: The error is Types of data mismatch in criteria expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the order of the parameter insertion.
This is crucial with OleDb because OleDb cannot recognize parameters by their name. It uses the position of the placeholder in the command text to assign the corresponding parameter value.

(OleDb uses, as parameter placeholder, the question mark, but not surprisingly, with Access you can use also the @ prefix probably to ease the upgrade to Sql Server).

So when you add as first parameter the @Categ one, OleDb takes its value and try to assign it to the IDVoce field. Of course this fails with the mentioned error.

But of course, you cannot supply more parameters than you set up in your query.

```
cmd1.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO FattureVoci 
       ([IDVoce],[CodiceArticolo],[Descrizione],[Quantita],[PrezzoUnitario]) 
       VALUES (@Id,@Prod,@Descr,@Qta,@Prezzo)";
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(this.id.Text));
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prod", this.Prodotto.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descr", this.Descrizione.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qta", Convert.ToInt32(this.Qta.Text));
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prezzo", Convert.ToDecimal(this.Prezzo.Text));


// Actually your query doesn't include these parameters, 
// so you can't put it in the collection
// cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", this.Data.Text);
// cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Categ", this.Categoria.Text);
// cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Iva", Convert.ToInt32(this.PartitaIVA.Text) );
//cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Intest", this.Intestatario.Text);
```

I have rearranged the parameter order of insertion to correspond to the field names but it seems that your field Prezzo is of type decimal, not integer, so a different conversion would be required if this is the case

As a last point, if the `IDVoce` field is an AutoIncrement field, then you can't pass a parameter for its value in the query, you leave the work to find the next autoincrement number to the database.

Comment: Oh, so basically the parameters that im not using I HAVE TO eliminate or make them comments? I cant leave them in the code so

Comment: I have commented them because I am not sure if you need them or not, actually, the command text doens't require them and, so, if you add them to the Parameters collection you could have an error (surely in Sql Server, not sure with OleDb and Access)

Comment: Thanks, I got it finally.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem1 :** You mentioned in your query that you are inserting values for 5 columns but you are adding 9 parameters to your Command Object.

**Problem 2:** i don't think that OleDB accepts the Named Parameters so you need to write your parameterised query as below:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO FattureVoci 
        ([IDVoce],[CodiceArticolo],[Descrizione],[Quantita],[PrezzoUnitario]) 
                              VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(this.id.Text));          
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prod", this.Prodotto.Text);         
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descr", this.Descrizione.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qta", Convert.ToInt32(this.Qta.Text));
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prezzo", Convert.ToInt32(this.Prezzo.Text));
```

Comment: Wasn't that named parameter problem specific to Access or was it to ODBC? I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @PatrickHofman both OleDb and ODBC have this limitation. Access allows the @ prefix

Comment: Well, im not adding the other parameters so I can leave them like that or not? im not using them in the query